# EF code-first: how to save two entity's data in one table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities called `ControllerBlock and ControllerAction`.

See the `GetControllerBlocks()` function then you can understand how I am populating two classes' data like master details. How can I use EF to store these two entities' data into one table?

Table structure like

```
ControllerName    ActionName
--------------    ------------
Home                Index
Home                DasBoard
Home                Chart
HR                  Leave
HR                  Loan
Payroll             view
Payroll             Edit
Payroll             Process
```

My sample code:

```
public class ControllerBlock
{
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public List<ControllerAction> ControllerActions { get; set; }
}

public class ControllerAction
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}

public List<ControllerBlock> GetControllerBlocks()
{
    // Set ActionActive herem, if necessary
    List<ControllerAction> homeActions = new List<ControllerAction>() {
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Index" },
        new ControllerAction {  ActionName = "DashBoard" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Chart" }
    };

    List<ControllerAction> hrActions = new List<ControllerAction>() {
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Leave" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Loan" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "NoticeBoard" }
    };

    List<ControllerAction> payRollActions = new List<ControllerAction>() {
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "View" },
        new ControllerAction {  ActionName = "Edit" },
        new ControllerAction { ActionName = "Process" }
    };

    List<ControllerBlock> actionBlocks = new List<ControllerBlock>()
    {
        new ControllerBlock(){ControllerName = "Home", ControllerActions = homeActions},
        new ControllerBlock(){ControllerName = "HR",  ControllerActions =  hrActions},
        new ControllerBlock(){ControllerName = "PayRoll",  ControllerActions =  payRollActions}
    };

    return actionBlocks;
}
```

I am working with EF code first so suggest best way to insert data in one table when I have two entities. If possible add some code hint for inserting the data into one table from two classes. Thanks

Comment: You cannot and you shouldn't even be trying to do this.

Comment: i heard this can be done by table split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to flatten the data into one sequence. That can be done using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).

Based on table structure, assuming Entity would look like

```
public class Entity {
    public string ControllerName { get; set; } 
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
```

Based on provided model.

```
var actionBlocks = GetControllerBlocks();
//Flatten the collection of block.
List<Entity> controllerActions = actionBlocks
    .SelectMany(b => b.ControllerActions
        .Select(a => new Entity { 
            ControllerName = b.ControllerName, 
            ActionName = a.ActionName 
         })
     )
    .ToList();
```

From there you should be able to save everything to one table.

Comment: No way two entity data can be saved in one table?

Comment: As far as I know that is not something EF can do

Comment: Please tell me why u use select many first and then select? Please guide me with reason.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, Read up on SelectMany here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx The explain it better than I would. They even have an example of how and why to use it.